# Ambiguous between methods in csharp project

Tags: c#

This is the main class:

```
public class ReportsParameter
{
    public ReportsParameter(string p, decimal? nullable);
    public ReportsParameter(string ParameterName, string Value);

    public string parameterName { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

In another class I use:

```
reportsParameters1.Add(new ReportsParameter("Title", txtTitle.Text));
reportsParameters.Add(new ReportsParameter("IsCurrency", null));
reportsParameters.Add(new ReportsParameter("IsInactive", null));
```

When I build the project, I get the following error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
>   'General.ReportsParameter.ReportsParameter(string, string)' and
>   'General.ReportsParameter.ReportsParameter(string, decimal?)'

The error occurred for the two lines that contain `IsCurrency` and `IsInactive`.

Can I use `DBNULL.Value.Tostring()`? Or is null different from dbnull?

Comment: How about creating a variable first and assigning that to the parameter?

Comment: Why not make the decimal not nullable? Then you could expose another constructor overload that does not take in decimal and set decimal to null internally. It is better for users as they don't need to explicitly pass in null for the decimal parameter.

Comment: Which method should be called in your opinion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because of having a nullable `decimal?` and `string` which is also nullable..

Try doing this.. to indicate the compiler the appropriate overload to be called.

```
reportsParameters.Add(new ReportsParameter("IsCurrency", (string)null));
```

OR

```
reportsParameters.Add(new ReportsParameter("IsInactive", (decimal?)null));
```

as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

To add to @bit's answer, it's possible that you can make your `ReportsParameter` class generic, depending on how you're using it afterwards. You get the benefit that it doesn't lose the type of the original parameter, meaning you get stronger type safety. You can also provide a default `null` value for the `value` parameter if none is specified:

```
public class ReportsParameter<T>
{
    public ReportsParameter(string name, T value = default(T))
    {
        _name = name; _value = value;
    }

    private readonly string _name;
    public string Name 
    { get { return _name; } }

    private readonly T _value;
    public T Value 
    { get { return _value; } }
}
```

And then pass the generic parameter when instantiating it:

```
// no need to pass the second parameter if it's null
list.Add(new ReportsParameter<string>("IsCurrency"));
list.Add(new ReportsParameter<double?>("IsInactive"));
```

One downside is that, to get type inference from the compiler, you also need a factory method like:

```
public static class Reports
{
    public ReportsParameter<T> CreateParameter<T>
        (string name, T value = default(T))
    {
        return new ReportsParameter<T>(name, value);
    }
}
```

Which allows you to skip the explicit generic parameter when the type can be inferred:

```
// no need to specify <string> in this case
reportsParameters1.Add(Reports.CreateParameter("Title", txtTitle.Text));

// but you need to do it here to resolve ambiguity
// (no need to pass the default value, however)
reportsParameters.Add(Reports.CreateParameter<string>("IsCurrency"));
reportsParameters.Add(Reports.CreateParameter<decimal?>("IsInactive"));
```